# extjs 4 get server response to a viewport

Tags: html, iframe, extjs

I'm new to Extjs.

I have an index.html file who contains an Ext.OnReady() function. A Viewport containing several items in different regions is created.
Each item in the Viewport has the 'html' attribute, holding an iframe tag.

For example, one of the regions :

```
region: 'center',
bodyBorder:false,
id: '...',
html: '<iframe SRC="./bla/bla" id="..." name="..."></iframe>'
```

Everything works fine, but I want to replace the iframes in something alternative. Is there another way to get a server response and load it into the Viewport's regions?

I've tried to replace the 'html' attribute with an 'url' attribute, but it didn't work.

```
region: 'center',
bodyBorder:false,
id: '...',
url: './bla/bla'
```

Comment: If all you need is a couple of iframes, you most certainly do not need ExtJS. What is the goal of your application? What is it that you are trying to accomplish? ExtJS is about fetching data from the server and using that in client side Controls. The app should be client side, not server side pushed into iframes - if you want to go the ExtJS route of building apps.

Comment: The application already exists, I just need to make this minor modification. I just need to get rid of the iFrames and replace them is something else. Everything should still work the same..

Answer (score 0):

If the app already exists you haven't built the app with ExtJS? If you did build separate apps with ExtJS that you want to integrate into one single app you risk name clashes.

Instead of having separate html files added into "html" of each region you would take the view files that your app consist of and add them as items in the item collection of each region in your border layout.

For an example, look at the MVC tutorial. [Here's a good start](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/guide/mvc_pt2).

I don't know why you think this would be a "minor modification"? Your views should be ExtJS components, not html files.

Comment: The application has a main screen which its layout built with ExtJS. The layout is a Viewport with several regions, each region holds an Iframe (using the <html> tag) that gets a response from the server and displays it.

I'm just required to change the Iframe into something else, another method to load the page returning as a response from the server into the region, is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, it's just not the way you build client side applications. You shouldn't be using ExtJS for this application, as most of the views are generated server side in the iframes. That is a server side rendered application. You don't need ExtJS if all you want is a border layout. It can be done with a few lines of JQuery/CSS instead.

Comment: The thing is that the application already exists as it is right now and I don't want to change its foundations too much. I'm just required to replace the iFrames with something else.
I don't know much about Ext JS so I've simply tried the 'url' tag but it didn't work, is there another way?

Comment: "I'm just required to replace the iFrames with something else." Replacing iframes with ExtJS is wrong in every way. It's not what you should do. If the only requirement is "replace the iframes", the requirement is wrong. Keep the iframes.

Comment: Sorry but it's not really my call. Isn't there a simple way in which I can load an HTML response from the server into a Viewport's region?

Comment: You could, but what would be the point? The original iframe solution is probably cheaper and better in every way. You could set the html of the panel in a region simply by doing thePanel.update(html); But I fail to see the need for ExtJS if all you need is a Viewport with the Border layout.